# How to get byte offset in a file in python

Tags: python, inverted-index

I am making a inverted index using hadoop and python. 
I want to know how can I include the byte offset of a line/word in python.
I need something like this

```
hello hello.txt@1124
```

I need the locations for making a full inverted index.
Please help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like this?

```
file.tell()
```

Return the file’s current position, like stdio's ftell().

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects

Unfortunately tell() does not function since OP is using stdin instead of a file. But it is not hard to build a wrapper around it to give what you need.

```
class file_with_pos(object):
    def __init__(self, fp):
        self.fp = fp
        self.pos = 0
    def read(self, *args):
        data = self.fp.read(*args)
        self.pos += len(data)
        return data
    def tell(self):
        return self.pos
```

Then you can use this instead:

```
fp = file_with_pos(sys.stdin)
```

Comment: Added wrapper class in the answer.

Comment: thank you for you response ... will try it out ... However, at present i have implemented a counter variable to keep a track of position. It is working pretty good as i need only relative location within a file.

Comment: @Siddharth: the code suggested by Wai seems to do exactly what your “present” code does. Unless you post your own code and mark it as *the* answer, please mark Wai's answer as the chosen answer.