# Continuously parse CSV files which are updated by another process

Tags: python, csv

If I have a bunch of `csv` files and they get updated periodically.
Let's say the csv files are:

```
file1.csv, file2.csv file3.csv
```

During the updating process, the data is appended to the last line of the `csv` file.

is it possible to read the data from the `csv` file and as it updated and store it in a `array` or `collection(deque)`.

Is there a way to collect the data from the csv file as it is updated?

Comment: What is updating the files?

Comment: the linux kernel tool - `perf`

Comment: If reading the data directly from `perf` is not an option, try a system like inotify – https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify to detect filesystem changes. Then just use the Python csv module.

Comment: lol. http://linux.die.net/man/1/perf-script-python

Comment: Reading data directly from `perf` is not possible.

Comment: @kojiro: that will not allow you to monitor the north bridge events :-)

Comment: This isn't a great question title: you might consider revising it to something a little more specific.

Comment: @MatthewSchinckel Any better?

Comment: Yes, that's heaps better Alex!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a python package called [Watchdog](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog).

This example shows monitoring the current directory recursively for file system changes, and logging any to the console:

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path='.', recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

You could use this in conjunction with Ignacio's answer - use `file_pointer.tell()` to get the current position in the file, and then `seek()` there next time, and read the remainder of the file. For example:

```
# First time
with open('current.csv', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    last_pos = f.tell() 

# Second time
with open('current.csv', 'r') as f:
    f.seek(last_pos)
    new_data = f.readlines()
    last_pos = f.tell()
```

Comment: if the python script doesn't running during the csv updating process. I think it will be better to pickle `last_pos` into a harddisk file to mark last read line.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the current size of the file with the current offset within the file. If the size is greater, read the new data.

Comment: Example? or some more explanation please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2104080/20862 http://stackoverflow.com/q/3642088/20862