# c++ to python conversion issues

Tags: c++, python, linux

Following my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784164/python-csv-parsing):
this is what i came up with:
perf_data is a vector.

```
void read_data() {
    long val;
    ifstream infile1("/foo/other");

    infile1 >> val;
    perf_data[1].first = val;
    infile1.close();

    ifstream infile2("/foo/core_0");

    infile2 >> val;
    perf_data[0].first = val;
    infile2.close();
}
```

In python as I understand, this cannot be done for a file or can it be?

Comment: Where did you get the 'understanding' that this cannot be done in python?!

Comment: I need to read it line by line and then append it to the `perf_data` assuming, perf_data is a collection or array. Pls correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: And what's wrong with python's `myfile.readline()`?

Comment: that's lack of knowledge!

Comment: @rnish: The description in the comment and the code in C++ don't quite go together. The code is reading a single value from each one of the two files using it to update an existing value in an array and then you close the files. There is no *line by line* and there is no *appending*.

Comment: Sure. this is a simplified case of it :-)

Comment: Can you be more succinct in your question as it seems unfair for people to have to read your previous post and then some C++ code to be asked ``... this can't be done or can it ...`` - Are you sill wanting to tail a CSV file as it's updated?

Comment: @sotapme: thank you. But I would implement it in python. using the suggestion `us2012` gave me. :-)

Comment: Well if ``myfile.readline()`` is the answer then I'm still unsure of the question :/