# Hadoop - Map function key when streaming

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I'm pretty new to Hadoop and I've come across something I'm unable to find out about with Google.

In the Java version of the "HelloWorld" Hadoop program which is word count, the mapper function takes in a key,value pair which is in line with my understanding of how MapReduce works. From my understanding, in the word count example, the key is the line number and the value is the line of text itself:

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    //Tokenize the line and print out token,1 for each
}
```

However, in the python streaming example for the same program, the python mapper doesn't seem to read the key:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
# input comes from STDIN (standard input)
for line in sys.stdin:
    # remove leading and trailing whitespace
    line = line.strip()
    # split the line into words
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        print '%s\t%s' % (word, 1)
```

It seems that the python mapper can only read the value part from the stdin. How can I get the key (the line number) in the python mapper too?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

here you are not using any hadoop framework function like map which gets the byte offset as the line number as the first argument (Framework library function pass this value when invoking the map function ). Since you are reading from standard input , you will have to write your custom implementation to print the line number. Something like this 
[How to get byte offset in a file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642088/how-to-get-byte-offset-in-a-file-in-python)

Hope this helps